# Find Taylor-Maclaurine expansion of function

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

Find Taylor-Maclaurine expansion of function: $f(x)=\sin(x)\cdot \cos(x) \cdot \arctan x^2$

my try: $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}\sin{2x} \cdot \arctan x^2$ and we have $\displaystyle \sin{2x} = \sum _{n=0} ^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n \cdot (2x)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!} $ and $\displaystyle \arctan x^2 = \sum _{n=0} ^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n \cdot x^{4n+2}}{2n+1} $ but I don't know how to find product of series

Comment: why would you want tp do this?

Comment: What you wrote is for $\sin(x)$ but not for $\sin(2x)$

Comment: Beside the fact that the series will look like $f(x)=x^3 P_n(x^2)$, I think it could be difficult to find the general expression of the coefficients of the polynomial.

Comment: Please, Maclaurin. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colin_Maclaurin

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici thanks, I've already corrected,     it's one of excersices, can we find radius of convergence of this series ?